# hogan.js how to debug a variable

Tags: node.js, express, hogan.js

i'm very familiar with the javascript **console.log()**, and the **php_dump()** functions that allows  us to see what's in a variable, i want to know if there is some function like this in hogan.js that let us **inspect** the content of a variable.

Comment: lo and behold, hoganJS. there's a new javascript library coming out every month.

Answer (score 1):

add some method to your data and include it at the loctation you need to inspect the scope

```
var data = {
  ...
  // your vars,
  ...
  inspect: function () {
    return function () {
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
};

template.render(data);
```

anywhere you use {{inspect}} it will log the current render context in the console

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified it to add the function to the data packet that is passed to Hogan in a centralized position, which, in my code, is a function called `render()`.
Thank you for this clever trick.

```
function render(template, data, destination) {
    data.inspect = function() {
        return function() {
            console.log("inspect:")
            console.log(this);
        };
    };
    // localized strings
    data.strings = app.strings;
    var tmpl = Hogan.compile(template);
    var content = tmpl.render(data);
    document.querySelector(destination).innerHTML = content;
}
```